# Error when running RGFClassifier

Tags: python, greedy

I recently tried to run Regularized Greedy Forest algorithm (rgf Classifier) from this package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rgf_python.

I did run pip install rgf_python, but when I tried to run the example this error pops out in spyder:

```
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rgf\sklearn.py", line 111, in <module>
    "config flag 'exe_location' to RGF execution file.".format(_EXE_PATH))

Exception: C:\Users\me\rgf.exe is not executable file. Please set config flag 'exe_location' to RGF execution file.
```

What should I change in order for config the flag 'exe_location'? May sound beginner but can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Official doccument is here.
https://github.com/fukatani/rgf_python#installation

For accurate support, I want to know your OS and python version.

In brief, you should do the following two things.

First, you should build rgf execution file.

$ git clone https://github.com/fukatani/rgf_python.git

$ cd rgf_python/include/rgf/build

$ make

If succeeded, you can find rgf_python/include/rgf/bin/rgf if you use linux.

Second, you should register exe_location.
There are several methods, but I recommend the method editing ~/.rgfrc.
Open ~/.rgfrc by  your text editer, and add line.

`exe_location=/path/to/rgf_python/include/rgf/bin/rgf.exe`

exe_location should be full path, please do not use relative path.

Thanks.